# Wasted satoshi due to transaction fees

Tags: transactions, wallet, transaction-fees, dust, micropayments

Say I have a wallet containing 1000 satoshi, and I want to transfer this to another wallet, but it doesn't cover the transaction fee, do I just waste it?

1. I don't have the private key to the wallet as it's an iOS wallet
2. The wallet won't let me set a zero transaction fee

Answer (score 1):

Is it BreadWallet? You can restore that in Mycelium, afaik.

As to your actual problem: just leave it, file the seed words somewhere safe, and maybe one day it'll be worth actual money.

Comment: It's the IndieSquare wallet. And there aren't any seed words :-(

Comment: Oh wait...yes there are :-)

Answer (score 0):

Deposit some Bitcoins into said wallet from another wallet, then withdraw the full amount (deposited amount + dust amount). That way your dust UTXO will be used to fund the withdrawal transaction back to your destination wallet.

Caveat: this action will cost more than the dust UTXO itself. But who's to say 1000 Satoshi wont be 1000 dollars in future

Comment: If the fees will cost more than 1,000 satoshi, why does it matter what 1,000 satoshi will be worth in the future?  If it costs you around 15,000 satoshi (current average fee for a resonable confirmation time) per transaction, and you need 2 transactions to pull this off, it means you are spending 30,000 satoshi to get 1,000.  It doesn't make any sense regardless of the BTC/USD conversion rate.

Comment: If one is patient enough and happy to broadcast the transaction during a not so busy period, one may get his transaction included in the Blockchain for FREE by broadcasting to a node with free relay policy and hoping that a miner picks up the transaction. It is a long shot, but perfectly doable.